# Can I run laravel (admin dashboard) and vue (front-end) in a single domain

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-8, vuejs3

I have done a project which admin dashboard is done by using laravel+vus (vue (v2.6) inside laravel(v8)) and front end is done by independent vue(v3) js(getting data from laravel api).can i run this two projects in a single domain.That is frond is will load [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and admin dashboard will load [www.domain.com/admin..Can](http://www.domain.com/admin..Can) I do like this.?Routing is enable in vuejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but typically it is easier to host the backend on a subdomain, e.g. you'd host the backend on something like `backend.domain.com` and the frontend on `domain.com` and/or `www.domain.com`. You can configure a setup like this relatively easy with nginx for example, by setting up two location blocks, one pointing to your Laravel installation, the other one to your vue 3 application.

To get back to your question, you can also set it up like you wanted, e.g. in a subfolder instead of via a subdomain. You can also do that via location blocks with nginx, but then you'd have to make sure that the routes from your backend and your frontend never have any overlap, so I wouldn't recommend to go that way.